# Java script to block video streaming on the webpage

Tags: javascript, embed, flashvars

I want to write a javascript which will be just put at the end of HTML pages and it should block the video streaming if its being done on those webpages.
Considering "embed" tag is used at many places, I tried writing below script which will link it to some webpage which has a jpeg image saying "Blocked Content" or something like that.

```
var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed"); 
for(var i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++){
   if(embeds[i].type == "application/x-shockwave-flash"){
       embeds[i].type = "image/jpeg"
       embeds[i].src = "Some link to a jpeg image on the web"           
       embeds[i].flashvars = {}
   }
}
```

One of the websites I tried putting this script has used "swfobject.embedSWF" to stream videos, which also has flashvars variable set. So I am also trying to reset the flashvars here. But its not working. Can anyone please suggest how can I do this ?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: I want to block the video streaming by disabling the features (that causes the streaming) on the webpages itself. Though there are several better ways of doing this, I want to do it by dynamically inserting the java script at the end of the HTML pages that are received by the browsers. I know of the ways of how to insert the script and have successfully tested them as well, just that I am struggling with the java script part.

Comment: Any pointers on this ?